# How to draw graphs Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and would like to plot values from one column versus the values from another column. Fortunately, there is plot method associated with the data-frames that seems to do what I need:

```
df.plot(x='col_name_1', y='col_name_2')
```

Unfortunately, it looks like among the plot styles (listed here after the kind parameter) there are not points. I can use lines or bars or even density but not points. How can I draw a graph with points?

Comment: `df.plot(kind='scatter', x='col1',y='col2')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import linear_model


#zamjena naziva atributa
stup = ['datum', 'srTemp', 'minTemp', 'maxTemp', 'oborine', 'vikend', 'potrosnja']
#1. ucitavanje datoteke
potrosnjaPive = pd.read_excel('D:/dat/potrosnja_pive.xlsx', names=stup)

#zamjena naziva mjeseci
replacements = {
   'vikend': {'DA':1, 'NE':0}
}
potrosnjaPive.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)
```